# Qual è il significato di "pieni di pretese" in questo brano?

Tags: meaning

Ciao,
sto leggendo il libro *L'amica geniale* di Elena Ferrante.
Nella pagina 153 c'è questa espressione che mi è vaga, qualcuno può aiutarmi?

> "I maschi che le ronzavano intorno erano quasi uomini, ***pieni di pretese***. Di conseguenza, tra progetto delle scarpe, letture sul mondo orribile dentro cui eravamo finite nascendo, e fidanzati, non avrebbero avuto più tempo per me."

I miei dizionari dicono che "pretesa" qui significherebbe "ambizioni" ma mi suona poco chiaro.
Grazie.

Comment: Quasi uomini significa giovani. Che cosa potrebbe pretendere un giovane uomo da una donna?

Comment: @AlessandroMandelli: Il testo precedente a quello riportato dall'OP dà a intendere che si tratti effettivamente di pretese di tipo amoroso.

Comment: Ecco il testo: «Temevo, tornando da scuola, di incontrarla e apprendere dalla sua stessa voce accattivante che ormai faceva l’amore con Peluso. O se non era lui, era Enzo. O se non era Enzo, era Antonio. O, che so, Stefano Carracci, il salumiere, o persino Marcello Solara: Lila era imprevedibile.»

Comment: Grazie ragazzi, ora il senso è molto chiaro. È la prima domanda che posto allora forse non ho ancora capito bene come devo ringraziarvi, ma qui vorrei ringraziare tutti quanti.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nel contesto che tu citi, questi ragazzi pieni di pretese sono esigenti, vogliono qualcosa a cui pensano di avere diritto.

Inoltre la scelta del verbo ronzare evoca il comportamento degli insetti che sono attratti attratti più o meno inconsapevolmente da qualcosa, determinando una sorta di "assedio".

Immagina una ragazza giovane e bella che ha una sacco di ragazzi che le ronzano intorno.

Da [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/pretesa/):

> Il fatto di pretendere, e anche ciò che si pretende: accampare,
>   avanzare una p., delle p.; spesso con connotazione negativa, richiesta
>   assurda e immotivata

e ancora più avanti

> Spesso al plur., e in usi assol., per indicare esigenze eccessive,
>   aspirazioni sproporzionate, dettate da un’esagerata opinione di sé:
>   una persona che ha molte, troppe p., carica di pretese

Answer (score 0):

Secondo me intende dire che questi uomini erano assillanti ed esigevano un sacco di cose (o di tempo o di attenzione) dalla persona di cui si sta parlando ed occupandone completamente il tempo e le energie.

Di solito si usa "pretesa" in modo negativo (nel senso di esigere qualcosa a cui si ha poco diritto).